# NuGet failed installing ImageSharp

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, imagesharp

I have been trying to install the imagesharp package via NuGet, but I am getting an error from the output window below:

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\mycomp\Source\Repos\WebApplication\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj...
Package SixLabors.ImageSharp 1.0.0-beta0001 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package SixLabors.ImageSharp 1.0.0-beta0001 supports:
 - netstandard1.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.1)
 - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
 Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication1'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.9032282
 ========== Finished ==========
```

And here from the Error List window:

```
    Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication1'.
```

I tried repairing VS 15.4.0 and also updating to VS 15.4.2, but none of it is fixing my issue....any thoughts?

Comment: How did you install this package? And what is your project type? It works fine to me to install this package to the ASP.NET core 2.0 project:https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai1sp_yvodHfek1czb1WV2eJmho. You can check the different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was quite simple in the end. It had nothing to do with the compatibility of the netcoreapp2.0, or either the netstandards1.1/netstandard1.3. That was just a symptom of the real issue. This is how I fixed it:

**Tools>Options>NuGet Package Manager>Clear All NuGet Cache/s.**

I did get another error while uninstalling from NuGet manager stating access denied to remove the BuildBundlerMinifier package, so I manually deleted it from my .nuget folder, installed SixLabors.ImageSharp package, then reinstalled the BuildBundlerMinifier again, then VOILA! It worked.

Every option that I did try to search for, were either confusing or totally unnecessary.

There is high probability that if you do run into any weird issues like this while installing/uninstalling your NuGet packages, its due to your NuGet cache folder/s.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are trying to install ImageSharp in a .Net Core 2.0 project which is not supported. See this line of error message:

*"Package SixLabors.ImageSharp 1.0.0-beta0001 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0"*

Comment: Oh. Thats interesting... Should I be working in netcoreapp1.1 instead?

Comment: Seems you need to use .Net Core 1. See this guide that shows who has implemented what version of net-standard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: I don't think this is actually the problem. It must be a symptom of the real issue. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try downgrade you project and see if anything different happens or not.

Comment: A project that targets .NET Core App 2.0 supports .NET Standard 1.0 through to 2.0. The rest of the error message indicates that SixLabors.ImageSharp has .NET Standard assemblies in it you should be able to install it into a .NET Core project. So there is something else going wrong here.

Comment: looks like a NuGet bug on install. restores fine when manually added to the project.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the compatibility check during package installation (not sure if because of an asset that is in an unexpected location or issues with package trimming on .NET Core 2.0 since it depends on prerelease versions of .NET Core packages). When you add the package manually to the csproj file, it should restore and build fine:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.0-beta0001" />
</ItemGroup>
```